# ViewChild is undefined within the templateUrl, but not the template

Tags: angular, code-injection, angular2-components

I am trying to do dynamic injection of a component in angular 4. 
I am successfully able to do this, but the problem I am having is when I am trying to tie it into a target

```
<div>
    <ng-template #detailedGrid></ng-template>    
</div>
```

When rendering in my code I keep getting an error that my target is not defined.

Here is the scaled down code:

```
@Component({    
    templateUrl: '../../common/components/grid/templates/grid.html'   
    //template: `<div #detailedGrid></div>`
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('detailedGrid', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {} 

ngAfterViewInit() {

const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DetailedListComponent);
        const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);  // <-- this one works
        // const ref = this.target.createComponent(factory); // <-- This one does not work
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

The one that works just essentially adds at the bottom of the page. What I am wanting to do is inject it into the div location

Error:

> Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

The "target" never gets defined.

So something interesting was when I put the code inside of template, the target code works, but when it is inside the templateUrl html code it does not.

**Update**: So I figured out the problem just not the solution

The problem is that my  tag in html is within another component's tag

Code is inside the html in this component

```
<grid></grid>
```

When I brought out div tag on the outside of grid component it worked.
So my question is how do I access it within grid component.

Comment: please post your full template..It mostly occurs when the element is enclosed within *ngifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution is to move the

```
@ViewChild('detailedGrid', {read: ViewContainerRef}) 
public detailedGrid: ViewContainerRef;
```

up into the GridComponent

Then reference the grid component as

```
@ViewChild(GridPageComponent) gridPageComponent: GridPageComponent;
```

Now I can access the target

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PatientsDetailedListComponent);            
const ref = this.gridPageComponent.detailedGrid.createComponent(factory);
ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```